# Writing tests for functional code?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, functional-programming

For the sake of example, suppose we're building a simple cache. We can take the functional approach using a closure:

```
makeCache = ->
  c = {}
  (key, fetch) ->
    if c[key]
      c[key]
    else
      c[key] = fetch()
      c[key]

cache = makeCache()
cache(1, -> 1)
```

The problem I find with this approach is that you can't test it easily. I want to be able to check that the `'1'` is in the cache. If I add more values, I want to make sure they are in the cache as well.

If I have a more complicated cache, like an LRU cache, I would want to test other aspects as well. However those variables are entirely hidden behind a closure.

I tend to think up solutions using a closures but then I resort to an object oriented style so that its testable:

```
class Cache
  constructor: ->
    @c = {}
  get: (key, fetch) ->
    if c[key]
      c[key]
    else
      c[key] = fetch()
      c[key]

cache = new Cache()
cache.get(1, ->1)
```

Now I have access to `cache.c` and any other variables that I need to inspect to test.

So my question is, how can you test your code when using a functional style closure?

Comment: Why do you think that caches are functional? That seems to be quite imperative :-) Btw, you'd rather pass the `fetch` function to `makeCache` and call it with the `key`.

Comment: Write a test for how you want the code to behave. That doesn't necessarily need introspection. Just test that `fetch` is not invoked multiple times for the same key…

Comment: how would you create a cache in a more declarative way? fetch is a function that will do some work to create the value if its not in the cache...

Comment: Declarative? Oh that's fine. I just meant it is not [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this not test for your specific case?

```
cache = new Cache()
cache.get(1, ->1)
expect(cache.get(1, ->0)).toBe(1);
```

The more general problem is real enough.  But it's true with any encapsulation technique.  I would argue, though, that the whole goal of testing, or at least of unit testing, is to work the public interface of a system.  So if you don't have a public facility to check whether something is in the cache, then you don't need a unit test for it.

There are certainly people who disagree with this, but I find it a bright dividing line.

Comment: So the real challenge is when you get into more complicated stuff. Like an LRU cache. But I do see your point -- test the interface rather than the internal workings.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And as Bergi pointed out there are often ways to test deeper as needed.  You could spy on the `fetch` function and just count the number times it's called.